# iOS weak linking a symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I distribute a static framework for iOS. In a new version, this uses `UIScribbleInteraction`, but when linking a host App with the library in Xcode 11 (which uses the iOS 13 SDK which does not contain `UIScribbleInteraction`) the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScribbleInteraction"
```

occurs.

I can make the symbol weak in the static framework by adding

```
asm(".weak_reference _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScribbleInteraction");
```

However the error still occurs when linking the host App. I can add

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup
```

To the host App's 'Other linker flags', but Xcode then produces a warning:

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup is deprecated on iOS Simulator
```

Is there any way to fix this issue that doesn't generate a warning (and preferably doesn't require any changes to the host App?)